# How to add a new field with a custom index to a managed package

Tags: custom-index

Our managed package is adding a brand new custom field that is marked as *external id* and therefore has a custom index associated to it. Through Salesforce's UI we can add a `Custom Index` component type to the managed package but whenever I try to add the custom index that is associated to the new field I get an error: "an internal server error has occurred".

Is the reason simply that we do not need to add a "custom index" object since the field is already marked as external id and that custom index is going to be created in the customer's Salesforce whenever they install the managed package? I just want to make sure that the field is going to be indexed in the customer's org.

Comment: I went ahead and created a release without adding the "custom index" object. The custom index has been created in the customer's org so it seems like my theory is correct.

Comment: Why not add that as an answer so this question doesn't remain open?

Comment: The key point here is that the field is an external ID and Salesforce automatically handles the index for these.